# Can't move to collection

Tags: collections, outliner, keymap

I have an object. There is no parenting or anything that I think would make it unable to move the collection. I have it in a collection but I need to move it to another. I don't have any collections inside other collections. So I am not sure what is going on.

it is the only object selected so I know it's not the problem where there is no active object, which has already been posted before. If I just press  <kbd>M</kbd> nothing happens. I am so confused. I can still, however drag and drop objects into different collections but this seems to slow of a workaround.

[image]

Comment: When this happens to me, I'm Usually not in object Mode.

Comment: @TomMorrow I have it in object mode.

Answer (score 1):

This can also happen if you are in *local view*. You are not able to move any object to another collection while in local view. It indeed will appear to have no effect when selecting that command and it will also not give any feedback that it cannot perform that action while in local view.

If the move command is indeed not working due to local view, You can simply exit local view by hitting the `/`-key (it toggles). Once you leave it, *move to collection* should work as normal.